# Using openssl to get server extension order for JA3S

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

### Goal

I want to get the JA3S fingerprint from openssl but it seems there is no way to retrieve the order from server hello since `tls_process_server_hello()` never saves the extension order.
The `RAW_EXTENSION` buffer are deleted in the end of `tls_process_server_hello()` instead of cached in `SSL_CONNECTION` like client hello message.

PS: If you're interested in how to get JA3 from openssl, please go to the last section. It's much easier after openssl 3.1.

### What I've done

Using `SSL_CTX_set_msg_callback` to get the packet from server hello and parsing it seems legit, but I wonder if there is a better way.

### Question

- Is there an existing api for getting the order of server extension?
- Or I missed some implicit context like "server extensions are in certain order"?
  (I have seens a server hello isn't in ascending order, so I presume there is no implicit rule for it)

Just want to know if I need to submit a PR to openssl

### Keywords

- openssl, server extensions, ja3 (but not much found)

### Relevant post on SO

- [Openssl API Client Hello callback function is never called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66658625/4123703)

### How about JA3?

If one is intereseted in JA3, a new api [`SSL_client_hello_get_extension_order()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_client_hello_get_extension_order.html) introduced in openssl 3.1 by this [PR](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/16910).

However I still parse the packet since I need JA3 without openssl in certain scenarios.